# Downloading file through PHP adds 26 new line characters at start using Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Trying to create a module that allows a user to upload a file, and re-download that file. Uploading the file works fine and the file is successfully saved. Manually checking that uploaded file shows that it is a valid file, and opens correctly. However downloading the file gives an invalid file (no matter what file type is uploaded).

After using an online file comparison tool, it turns out that the downloaded file adds 52 bytes worth of new line characters (26 lots of 0D 0A), which means the last 52 bytes of the actual file is missing.

The code I've got for downloading the file is as follows:

```
$response = new Stream();
$response->setStream(fopen($fileName, 'rb'));
$response->setStatusCode(200);

$headers = new Headers();
$headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($fileName) .'"')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', filesize($fileName))
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
        ->addHeaderLine('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

$response->setHeaders($headers);
return $response;
```

Any suggestions on why this may be happening? Many thanks.

Comment: @tlenss ob_clean() and flush() solved it, been scratching my head over it all morning and no example I read online included those 2 lines! If you put it as an actual answer, I'll mark it as correct! Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you echo or print something to screen before this code executes?

Comment: @AycanYaşıt Not myself, but maybe Zend outputted something beforehand without me realising. tlenss seems to have deleted his comment now, but his solution of putting `ob_clean()` and `ob_flush()` before the return statement worked for me :)